# How to run cpp file in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, objective-c++

I am trying to run the code from below link which contains C++ codes.

https://github.com/cjcliffe/CubicVR

This link contains the BeatDetektor app for iPhone. But this is developed using C++. How can i run this project?? There are no xcode project file. Also i am trying to run main.cpp file but there are lots of package files error...

below is link for BeatDetektor app
http://www.cubicvr.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=67&Itemid=82

Can anyone tell me how to run C++ file in Xcode or on terminal???

Comment: I think your question is too unclear to answer at the moment.  Maybe you could post what you've tried and what errors you are getting.

Comment: Your questions is confused:  you cannot "run" a project or a file.

Comment: Hello Richard, I got the solution... please see below my answer

Comment: Neither your question nor your answer make sense.  I'd vote to close if I had the privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [CMake](http://cmake.org/) software i am able to convert my cpp project to Xcode project... As github code contains .make extension file...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is an IDE, not a compiler. It builds targets of various types by using a compiler like GCC internally. If there is no Xcode project file, you can create one yourself and add the source files to it. As far as I know Xcode will not compile source files on their own.